# Putting 2 ImageViews side by side

Tags: android, imageview

I am attempting to put two android ImageViews side on the same line, with one gravitated to the left and the other to the right.  The 2nd image ends up positioned below the first.  I would like to fix this and put them both on the same line.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+android:id/expandIcon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_float" 
    />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+android:id/expandIcon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_float" 
    />
```

Comment: What kind of layout are these ImageViews in?

Comment: Why don't you put them in a horizontal oriented linearLayout?

Comment: Use linear layout with horizontal gravity

Comment: Did you try using a RelativeLayout as parent layout and then set layout_alignParentLeft=true for the first and layout_alignParentRight for the second image?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not believe they should have the same "android:id" either.

Comment: @William exactly, that's another issue in that layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in horizontal linear layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+android:id/expandIcon1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_float" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+android:id/expandIcons2"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_float"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`layout_gravity="left"` and `layout_gravity="right"` won't do anything in a horizontal `LinearLayout` since they are already positioned left-to-right.

Make the parent `Layout` a `RelativeLayout` and use `alignParentright="true"` for the second one. By default, the first one will be placed to the left of the `parent`.

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/expandIcon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_float" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+android:id/expandIcons"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_float"?>
</RelativeLayout >
```